# Calling Break Method

Tags: c#, loops, methods, break

Is it possible to call a method witch can break a loop from where it was called?

For example:

```
    void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You can only break from loops. So no.

Comment: Is there multithreading involved here?

Comment: It's not possible. BTW - Keep in mind that `Stop()` can be called from other parts of your code, that do not even contain a loop (and the MSIL code for it would have to somehow manage both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible directly. But you can use a method that returns a `bool` to indicate if the loop should be canceled (shown in other answers). Another way is to use a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-6.0) which can be used in threads or tasks but even in a synchronous loop:

```
void Run(CancellationTokenSource cancelToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
        Console.WriteLine("Still working...");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
// cancel it after 3 seconds, just for demo purposes
cts.CancelAfter(3000);
Program p = new Program();
p.Run(cts);
Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
```

This breaks the loop after 3 seconds. If you want to break after a certain condition you can call the [`Cancel` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 4):

No, `break` is a statement and has to appear directly inside a loop (that's how the syntax defines it. If it appears without an enclosing loop, you get a syntax error).

It cannot be used from within a method to break out of an outer loop. However, you can change the method to return a bool instead:

```
void Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (Stop())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

bool Stop()
{
    return true; // return true or false, depending on whether you'd like to break out of the loop.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible but if you want a other methode you could do this

```
void Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if(Stop())
           break;
    }
}

bool Stop()
{
    //some calculation that returns true if the loop needs to break
}
```